# 500 (Internal Server Error) con AJAX y PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, formularios

Tengo un formulario el cual envia 3 datos hacia el archivo php `guardar_lugar.php` y al momento de apretar el boton `guardar` me ocurre el error.
He leido varias respuestas de diferentes foros pero no he podido resolever el problema.

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Formulario**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-center">                   
                    Formulario de Edición de Lugares</h3>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="idlugar" name="idlugar" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" id="opcion" name="opcion" value="registrar">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control"  autofocus></div>               
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="direccion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dirección</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input id="tipo" name="tipo" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                        <input id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
                        <input id="btn_listar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Listar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
var guardar = function(){
        $("form").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var frm = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'consultas/guardar_lugar.php',
                data: frm
            }).done( function( info ){
            console.log( info );        
            });
        });
    }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
include("dbinfo.php");

$idlugar = $_POST["idlugar"];
$opcion = $_POST["opcion"];
$informacion = [];

if ($opcion == "modificar" || $opcion == "registrar") {

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $dire = $_POST["direccion"];
    //$desc = $_POST["descripcion"];
    //$corr = $_POST["correo"];
    //$lati = $_POST["latitud"];
    //$longi = $_POST["longitud"];
    /*$urbRu = $_POST["selurbanorural"];
    $sector = $_POST["selsector"];*/
    $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
}

switch($opcion){
    case 'modificar':
        modificar($nombre,$dire);
        break;
    case 'eliminar':
        eliminar($idlugar,$con);
        break;
}

function modificar($nombre,$dire){

    $query = "UPDATE Lugar 
    SET Nombre='$nombre', Direccion='$dire'
    WHERE Id=$idlugar;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    verificar_resultado($result);
    cerrar($con);
}

function eliminar($idlugar,$con){

    $query = "DELETE FROM Lugar
    WHERE Id=$idlugar;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    verificar_resultado($result);
    cerrar($con);
}

function verificar_resultado($result){
    if(!$result) $informacion["respuesta"] = "Error";
    else $informacion["respuesta"] = "Bien";
}

function cerrar($con){
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: un error 500 significa que el error está en el servidor, o sea en tu código php

Comment: comienza analizando si las variables llegan bien al array $_POST,

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas las llaves en tus if... else...?: `if(!$result)  { $informacion["respuesta"] = "Error"; } else { $informacion["respuesta"] = "Bien"; }`?

Comment: he intentado verificar si los datos llegan y coloque entremedio del codigo unos echo para mostrar los datos pero el archivo php me sigue mostrando el error

Comment: Solucionaste el error? estoy en las mismas

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer en estos casos es activar los errores de PHP, ejecutar el programa para forzar el error y analizar la respuesta del archivo con la consola de depuración del navegador (la de chrome es la mejor para mi gusto).

Para ello lo primero es activar los errores de php con las siguientes funciones:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Luego tienes que analizar la respuesta del servidor en la consola de depuración, para ello:

1. Abre la consola de depuración en la página del error.
2. Ejecuta la función AJAX para forzar el error.
3. Dirigete a la pestaña "Networks".
4. Busca el archivo php que quieres analizar (en tu caso
   guardar_lugar.php) y haz click en él.
5. Haz click en la pestaña
   "Response" de dicho archivo.

Si todo ha ido bien debería aparecerte el error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deberías activar los errores para ver dónde está el problema, con error_reporting(0); desactivas todas las notificaciones de error.
2. Mirar el fichero errors.log del servidor, pues se trata de un error PHP y muy probable la respuesta esté ahí.
3. Como usas un include, puede que el error esté en el fichero dbinfo.php, deberías postearlo también.